# Implementing inheritance in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, puppet

In Puppet the nodes can have a inheritance hierarchy which is good for re-use. You can define common variables and classes that comprises the foundation of a set of derived nodes.

However in Chef I couldn't find a similar construct. The only hierarchy I've come across so far is the attributes.

Can attributes be directly mapped to Puppet node inheritance? Common variables can be defined and overridden (Puppet class parameters) by the use of include_attribute, but what about calling other recipes?

One solution I can think of is to mention a dependency in the metadata file.

Is this a common practice?

UPDATE: What I've done so far is to create recipe's and managed dependencies using include_attribute and include_recipe, and then create roles for each collection of recipe's that should appear. This seems to be the best approach right now, since Library, Application, Wrapper pattern is too 'granular' for the requirements I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes can be defined in many places, including [cookbooks](http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_cookbooks.html), [roles](http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_roles.html) and [environments](http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_environments.html). I think this is concept is pretty well explained in the [About Attributes](http://docs.getchef.com/chef_overview_attributes.html) section of the documentation.

In fact, this big variety of freedom while setting node attributes, requires some constraints in a particular infrastructure (to avoid confusion). One idea is described in the article [Environment Cookbook Pattern](http://blog.vialstudios.com/the-environment-cookbook-pattern/). Maybe this gives you an idea, how you can handle this with Chef.

Comment: That is a really good read Stephen, although it falls a little bit further from somewhat specific requirements I've faced. I will update the question with the approach I've taken.

Comment: I've never seen anybody using `include_attributes`, but good if out works for you. So it might not be a "standard" use of Chef, but feel free to use this approach.